Gueant Optimal Market Making 5.15
I'm reading Optimal Market Making by Gueant, and I was trying to go through the results in the paper step by step.
I am just curious how Gueant arrives at the step right below (5.15) on page 28:
$$\delta_{\gamma}^{i, b*}(p) = \Lambda^{i, b^{-1}}(\gamma H_{\gamma}^{i, b}(p) - \frac{H_{\gamma}^{i, b'}(p)}{\Delta^i})$$
I can see how this makes sense reverse engineering it, but I'm just not sure how to construct that originally. In the single asset case, Gueant derives a similar formula to get (3.11), but the explanation is just "or equivalently by".
Using $H_{\xi}^{i, b}(p) = sup_{\delta} \frac{\Lambda^{i, b}(\delta)}{\xi}(1-e^{-(\xi \Delta^i (\delta - p)}))$, how can we arrive at the $\delta$ at which the supremum is attained? Is there a natural interpretation of these $H$ functions?
Note: I can get to his formula for $p$, just not for $\delta$
